# как изменить data при изменении route.query.page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

например если перейти на 3 страницу пагинациии, а потом нажать в браузере назад, route.query.page меняется, а контент не меняется, если просто кликать по пагинации то все норм, url и контент меняется, как отследить url и менять контент при клике на кнопку назад в браузере?
url такой: http://localhost:3000/category/610?page=3
например что бы когда меняется: ->  ?page=3 был равен pageNum

```
<div class="page"
                 v-if="filteredProducts.length > 20"
                 v-for="page in pages"
                 :key="page"
                 :class="{'page__selected' : page === pageNum}"
                 @click="pageClick(page)">
                {{ page }}
            </div>
data() {
    return {
      view: true,
      productsPerPage: 20,
      pageNum: 1,
}}
computed:{
paginatedProducts() {
      let from = (this.pageNum - 1) * this.productsPerPage,
        to = from + this.productsPerPage;
      return this.filteredProducts.slice(from, to);
    },
}
methods:{
pageClick(page) {
      this.$router.push({
        query: {
          ...this.$route.query,
          page: page,
        },
      })
      this.pageNum = page;
    },}
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `watch`, чтобы отследить изменение `page` из `$route.query`, допустим таким образом:

```
watch: {
    async "$route.query.page"() {
      this.pageNum = this.$route.query.page || 1;
    },
  },
```

и уже имея зависимое от `$route.query.page` свойство `pageNum` организовать логику построения пагинации.

[Более подробная информация о методах наблюдателях](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Пример, использования вышеуказанной информации в действии:
https://codesandbox.io/s/query-params-forked-9ieun

Comment: спасибо! работает отлично

Comment: Запись выглядит конечно не эстетично. Я бы посоветовал вам создать геттер в `computed` объекте и уже следить непосредственно за ним.

Comment: я бы тоже много чего сделал, если бы знал для чего это делать)